# Chrome.storage: how long does it last?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How long does data in `chrome.storage` last and when is it deleted? could data in there last past the end of a browsing session, past updates? If not, I need a way to perform long-term storage with my chrome extension.

<sub>P.S. I'm setting this in a client script, if that makes a difference</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it lasts past browser restarts or updates. Its never deleted unless you uninstall chrome or delete the user.
wouldn't make sense to go away after a browsing session.

Comment: Thanks... It would be nice if you could have something to back that up, but its good enough. Now I have to figure out why it is disappearing.

Comment: Im sure its documented, tho it would be redundant as that's the whole point storage exists. Otherwise what would be the point if its the same as storing in memory? Look up my chrome extension code (github plus for trello) and see how im using chrome.storage both from the content script and background. Both work.

Comment: also check if you are allowing/running in incognito. if you you might need to configure it on the manifest.